# How to properly use RewriteRule in Laravel 5.5 project?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

This .htaccess is working only for http://localhost/ but I want http://localhost/portal:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !portal/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /portal/public/$1 [L]
```

url in browser is http://localhost/ , http://localhost/login and so on, when I changed it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !portal/public
RewriteRule /portal(.*) /portal/public/$1 [L]
```

url in browser is redirecting to http://localhost/portal/public/index.php instead of displaying http://localhost/portal/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel, why not make use of its functionality?

You can simply achieve by [`Route Group Prefixes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-prefixes)

```
Route::prefix('portal')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/portal/users" URL
    });
});
```

Comment: My directory structure is: /wamp64/www/portal/public /wamp64/www/portal2/public and I need have access to Laravel apps via localhost/portal and localhost/portal2

Comment: you should rethink the application structure. there are security risks if you expose any content outside the public folder

Comment: laravel suppose that you config the `/public` folder as `DocumentRoot`